# Reporting Services. Different cell width and height

Tags: reporting-services

1. When I use my report on a server, I get normal width and height (CanGrow is True) of the cell.

   [image]
2. When I try to save as Excel, I have width of the cell less then I expected.

   [image]
3. When I try to save as Word, I have bad cell`s width and height.

   [image]
4. Finally when I try to save as pdf, I have normal cell`s width and height, but have a blank page after after each page of the report.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Jonnus, yes, You are right. I mean CanGrow propety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exporting SSRS to Excel and Word can produce unexpected (and undesired) behaviours.

**Excel**

Regarding the export to Excel - according to the answer on [this page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/52722c38-a767-470f-8a12-dd3bc417d1eb/row-height-not-preserved-when-exporting-to-excel?forum=sqlreportingservices)

> Excel itself doesn't really have a concept of CanGrow and CanShrink - rather, all it can do is
>
> 1. keep row heights at a static value (which it will do if both of those properties [CanGrow and CanShrink] are False), or
> 2. "snap to fit".

This does mean you are forced, if you want to export the data to excel, to define a static row height for the report

**Word**

I can recreate your problem - unfortunately this is a "feature" when exporting to Word.  The [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283105.aspx#WordLimitations) specifically states

> - Text boxes grow when they contain non-breaking spaces.

**PDF**

PDFs creating a blank page between report pages is usually an indication that your Report Body is wider than your printed page (in Report Properties).  Check your report is not too wide - even if there is no data displayed in the whitespace.